# Match any string which contains the "Error" expect "Errors: 0"

Tags: python, regex, match

How to write a regular expresion that matches any string which contains "Error" except "Errors: 0", i.e. when it ends with 0.

For example: When the string ends with "Errors: 1" it should match.

Now I'm using this regexp  with `re.match`:

```
r'^.*ERROR|FATAL|PROBLEM.*$'"
```

However, it matches all the string that contains "Error".

Comment: Are you using it with `re.search`?

Comment: I'm using  re.match

Comment: Oh my, that is even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `re.match(r'^.*ERROR|FATAL|PROBLEM.*$', s)` matches:

- `^.*ERROR` - start of string (that is redundant since `re.match` anchors the pattern at the beginning of string by default), any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars, and then `ERROR`
- `FATAL` - (at the beginning of the string only due to `re.match`!)
- `PROBLEM.*$` - `PROBLEM` at the beginning of the string and then any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars.

You may want to use

```
re.search(r'(?:ERROR(?!S:\s*0$)|FATAL|PROBLEM)', s, flags=re.I)
```

where `ERROR(?!\s*0$)` will match any `ERROR` anywhere inside a string that is not followed with `S:`,0 or more whitespaces (`\s*`) and end of string (`$`).

See [an online Python demo](https://ideone.com/yHaBvl)

To further enhance the pattern, consider using `\b` around the `(...)` to match the words `ERROR`, `FATAL`, and `PROBLEM` as whole words.

Comment: The outer brackets aren't necessary, because the pattern is put into brackets implicitly. (e.g. only `r'ERROR(?!S:\s*0$)|FATAL|PROBLEM'`)

Comment: @xZise: True, but if the `\b` word boundaries around are necessary, it would be easier for OP to modify the pattern. Else, the original issue will reoccur when the alternations were misgrouped (well, they were not grouped at all). Sometimes, like here, it might be better to keep the pattern a bit more verbose.

Comment: Also, FYI: if the lookahead check should be applied to each alternative branch, the grouping will be necessary: `r'(?:ERROR|FATAL|PROBLEM)(?!S:\s*0$)'`